# Deriving a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following information:

> $$\mathrm{i})\;\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial
>  t}=D\frac{\partial^2\theta}{\partial x^2}\qquad
>  \mathrm{ii})\;Q=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\theta
>  (x,t)\,dx\qquad\mathrm{iii})\;\theta (x,t)=\frac{Q}{\sqrt{Dt}}f(z)$$
>
> Where $f$ is some function and $z=x/\sqrt{Dt}$. It is also given that $Q$ and $D$ are constant.

I am asked to show that:

$$\frac{d^2 f}{dz^2}+\frac{z}{2}\frac{df}{dz}+\frac{1}{2}f=0$$

Is there a neat way of getting to this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $D$ also constant? Is it positive?

Comment: @MPW Yes it is!

Comment: If by a __lot__ of algebra, you mean finding partial derivatives using (iii) and stuffing them into equation (i), that seems like the obvious approach; it didn't _seem_ like a huge amount just now.  I'm not sure what info I can get out of (ii) that I can use, though.

Comment: Are you sure that the resulting equation is not: $$f''(z)+\frac{z}{2} f'(z) = 0?$$

Comment: @Dmoreno I am sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, let me give you a hint:

You have, by applying the chain rule to every term and remembering that $z = z(x,t)$:

$$\begin{align}
\theta_t = - \frac{1}{2} \frac{Q}{\sqrt{D}} t^{-3/2} f(z(x,t)) + \frac{Q}{\sqrt{D}}t^{-1/2} \frac{\partial f(z(x,t))}{\partial t} = -\frac{D Q f\left(z\right)}{2 (D t)^{3/2}}-\frac{Q x f'\left(z \right)}{2 D t^2}, 
\end{align}$$

since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = f'(z) \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}.$ And, on the other hand:

$$\theta_{xx} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{Dt}} \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left(\frac{Q}{\sqrt{Dt}} f'(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{Dt}} \right) = \frac{Q}{Dt \sqrt{Dt}} f''(z),$$

since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = f'(z) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}.$ Substitute every term back into the original PDE, i.e, $\theta_t - D \theta_{xx} = 0$ and recall that $z = x/\sqrt{Dt}$ in order to get the ODE-2 for $f(z)$:

$$ f''(z) + \frac{z}{2} f'(z) + \frac{1}{2} f(z) = 0.$$

The new variable $z$ is called *self-similar variable* and $f(z)$ *self-similar solution* or *similarity solution*. This kind of simplifications (from PDE to ODE) is very useful when considering dimensional analysis in some problems in fluid mechanics, such as the Blasius boundary layer problem.

Cheers!